# Get multiple months start and end date within a larger date range

Tags: sql, date, range

So what im struggling with is lets say i input a start date of the 1st of Jan and end date of the 31st of May, what i need to be returned is:

```
Jan Start Date, Jan end Date
Feb start Date, Feb End date
March start Date, March End date
April start Date, April End date
May start Date, May End date
```

The purpose of this is to then filter the data in a temp table to return the data that falls in each months range, so for this example the table would return 5 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the output you've specified:

```
declare @start DATE = '2022-01-01'
declare @end DATE = '2022-05-31'

;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month, 1, date) < @end
)
select     [Start Date] = date,
           [End Date]   = DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month,1, date))
           
from months
```

Comment: @Nikita, does this query work for you?

Comment: Yes thanks so much!

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer please? That kinda what motivates people to help each other on here :-)